# How do I get system date and time in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, localtime, systimestamp

I am using oracle apex when ever I try the code

```
SELECT TO_CHAR (SYSTIMESTAMP) "NOW" FROM DUAL
```

The result is always behind 5 hours. Can any one help me for this query?

Comment: Are you looking for the time on the database server?  The client?  Something else?  What time zone is the database server using?  What time zone do you want the result in?

Comment: Try [systimestamp at local](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Datetime-Expressions.html) or [current_timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.html). (I would write this as an answer but I don't have Apex to test with.)

Answer (score 5):

To get the time on the database server:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL
```

Or, if you want to format it as a string:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM')
FROM   DUAL;
```

---

If you want the time on the client then:

```sql
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;
```

or, you can take the system time and convert it to local time:

```sql
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP AT LOCAL FROM DUAL;
```

(Or you can format either as a string by wrapping it in `TO_CHAR`)

---

*Note: when you state "The result is always behind 5 hours", you need to make sure you also compare time zones.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=04eed27d59eb9098aef2b51e42995a42)*